# React Navigation cache component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am fairly new to React Native and a little confused with the following. I've set up a `StackNavigator` as shown

```
const MyProjectNavigator = StackNavigator({
  home: {screen: Other},
  latest_news: {screen: LatestNews}
}
```

When I want to go to a different screenm the navigation I perform is:

```
navigate(
  latest_news, {
    otherParams : param1
  }
);
```

**This works well so far.**

Now, assume that the **latest_news** component queries a lot of data from a server when mounted, then performs lots of operations on that data, sorting by date, author, yadda yadda. This takes some time to complete.

How would you suggest I made this faster? On iOS for example i would normally keep my `ViewController` in memory and if it was available, display that. When using `navigate()`, the navigator **seems to create a new instance** of the component thus reloading and re-processing everything from the beginning making the users wait every time.

***TL;DR**

*I want to keep all the data my component has queried and processed across navigation so that the processing doesn't have to repeat constantly.
I could just put the data on the global object but that doesn't sound like a good solution*

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Or is there a configuration that tells the navigator to use an existing component if the key used in the navigation function is the same?

Comment: This answer might be helpful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49968697/3436671

Answer (score 3):

You can use the TabNavigator instead of the StackNavigator.

TabNavigators reuse the same instances of its route items.

you can disable the visibility of the TabBar:

```
const TabNav = TabNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomePage},    
    NewsFeed1: { screen: NewsFeed}  ,
    NewsFeed2: { screen: NewsFeed}  ,
    NewsFeed3: { screen: NewsFeed}  ,
     // ...
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarVisible: false,
        }),});
```

and then you can navigate manually - for example with a button:

```
<Button title="NewsFeed1" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("NewsFeed1") }/>
```

Have a look at a simple example:

https://github.com/chrisdie/AwesomeNavigation/blob/master/src/tabbar2/App.js